# Load failure: [14] Not Found while installing windows

Tags: windows, boot, ntfs

I have `HP omni 10 5601tw` which came with windows 8.1 preinstalled os. Currently i am running windows 10 pro. I am trying to clean install windows 8.1. I am using rufus to create bootable windows.

> Here's what i have done
>   I am using gpt parition scheme for uefi

when i create using NTFS it gives me following error
[image]

When i create using fat32 it doesn't detect my pendrive as bootable device

But when i use windows 10 iso to as ntfs it works perfectly fine

I have disabled secure boot and clear secure boot keys

Windows 8.1 image is official Microsoft image download using Microsoft media creation tool. And Windows 10 is not official image its was downloaded from torrent

Windows 8.1 is not currupted or anything because previously i managed to installed it on my tablet. But this time its not working

Comment: "Windows 10 is not official image its was downloaded from torrent". You should download the image from Microsoft.

Comment: The error mentioning `bootia32.efi` means that the UEFI firmware on your computer is 32 bit, not 64 bit. You will not be able to install a 64bit version of Windows if that's what you are trying to do: You __MUST__ install a 32 bit version of Windows.  I suggest that you download an official 32 bit Windows 10 ISO from [Microsoft's Tech Bench](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench).